# How to move react-map-gl-geocoder position to the right

Tags: css, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, geocoder

I'm using a Geocoder element with my Mapbox map - specifically react-map-gl-geocoder.
I'm wanting to move the element to the right but I can't seem to override the styles given to it.

In the image below, you can see the search at the top-left corner. I want to be able to apply some sort of margin-left/left with a value of 50 so that it is next to the map navigation buttons.

Using className nested with the geocoder does not work.

```
    <Geocoder
      mapRef={mapRef}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.SOME_MAPBOX_API_KEY}
      onViewportChange={(viewport) => setViewport(viewport)}
      transitionDuration={1000}
      position="top-left" // To determine set position of geocoder search bar
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - there is a property called containerRef that allows you to style the Geocoder and place where you want

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-map-gl-geocoder

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a CSS rule that more specifically targets the element you want to affect. E.g, the one you want to change is `.mapboxg1-ctrl-top-left`, so you should try and overwrite it by using `.mapboxg1-control-container .mapboxg1-ctrl-top-left`. If that doesn't work, as a last resort you can try introduce the `!important` directive.

```css
// try first
.mapboxg1-control-container .mapboxg1-ctrl-top-left {
    left: 50px;
}

// if the above doesnt work, then use !important
.mapboxg1-control-container .mapboxg1-ctrl-top-left {
    left: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, im using React and imported the component. Where would I override the class? Thanks!

Comment: You could either put the style in the projects main CSS file (if there is one), or just create a new style.css file, add the rule to that file, and then import the new CSS file at the top of the component, e.g, import './App.css';.